# Link C ++ files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++

Hello Stack Overflow Community!  How do I link multiple C ++ files (.cpp, .h)?  In Object Oriented programming with C ++ a class separates the interface from the implementation (interface header file, implementation file .cpp).  And there is a third .cpp file that contains the Main function.  How do you compile and link those three files in Visual Studio Code ???

Comment: Use a build-system like `make` to build multiple files? Or use tools like CMake to create build-files (for example for `make`)? Then edit your `tasks.json` file to use whatever build system you've picked.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is an Editor. If you want to compile/link files you have to use a build system.

Comment: I have MinGW installed

Comment: @ManuelVillagraAvellán which includes GNU make